# Getting Null Reference exeption in Razor View but no breakpoint in OnGet method is hitting

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I am using `.Net Core 7 Razor Pages` and for my page I have an `OnGetAsync` which will get data from the database and fill a model so it can be used in the html view but either the `OnGetAsync` action is not firing off OR it is not being allowed to finish processing before the page is getting rendered. When I open the page I get a `null reference exception` for `Model.Sections` at the view level so I put a brake point on the line after the call to the DB and that break point does not get hit before the error happens. I have tried comparing my code to a few examples and I can't find anything wrong.

Relavant HTML page code:

```
@page
@model ManageSectionVM

<h2 class="Title">
    Manage Section Information
</h2>

<form id="Form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" autocomplete="off">
    <p>
        <label asp-for="SelectedSectionID">Update Existing Section?</label>

        <select asp-for="SelectedSectionID" asp-items="Model.Sections">
            <option value="0">Add New Section</option>
        </select>
    </p>
```

c# code:

```
using FFInfo.AdminUI.Models;
using FFInfo.BLL.Admin.Interfaces;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;

namespace FFInfo.AdminUI.Pages.Sections
{
    public class ManageSectionModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly ISectionHelper _sectionHelper;

        public ManageSectionModel(ISectionHelper sectionHelper)
        {
            _sectionHelper = sectionHelper;
        }

        [BindProperty]
        public ManageSectionVM ManageSectionVM { get; private set; } = new ManageSectionVM();

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync()
        {
            ViewData["Title"] = "Manage Section";
            var secitons = await _sectionHelper.GetSectionList();
            ManageSectionVM.Sections = new SelectList(secitons, "ID", "Name");
            ManageSectionVM.Synopsis = "Sorry, we do not have a synopsis available at this time.";
            return Page();
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
        {

            return Page();
        }

        public async Task<JsonResult> OnPostGetBasicSectionInfoAsync(int sectionID)
        {
            return new JsonResult(await _sectionHelper.GetBasicSectionInfo(sectionID));
        }
    }
}
```

If I remove the Model.Sections line the page will render up fine but no break point will still be hit in the c# code AND the title property will not be set. It is like it is just completely ignoring `OnGetAsync`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your page you should change `@model ManageSectionVM` to `@model ManageSectionModel`. Then change `asp-items="Model.Sections"` to `asp-items="Model.ManageSectionVM.Sections"` and `asp-for="SelectedSectionID"` to `asp-for="ManageSectionVM.SelectedSectionID"`.

```
@page
@model ManageSectionModel

<h2 class="Title">
    Manage Section Information
</h2>

<form id="Form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" autocomplete="off">
    <p>
        <label asp-for="ManageSectionVM.SelectedSectionID">Update Existing Section?</label>

        <select asp-for="ManageSectionVM.SelectedSectionID" asp-items="Model.ManageSectionVM.Sections">
            <option value="0">Add New Section</option>
        </select>
    </p>
</form>
```

Razor pages should have as model the class that extends `PageModel`, in your case `ManageSectionModel`.

Comment: Thanks I was looking at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-rp/crud?view=aspnetcore-7.0#overposting (the ViewModel part jus a bit down) and got confused as they changed the model name to "CreateVMModel" so I thought I had to change mine too. After trying your fix, which worked, I looked that page over a few more times and see they did the same thing you said to do.